# Calling RANDOM_NUMBER in a Fortran DLL

Tags: fortran, gfortran, dllexport

I want to compile and link a dynamic link library (dll) from a Fortran code using gfortran (mingw - 64bit) in windows. I test generated dlls in Excel 64-bit. I noticed, Excel does not return any result (it returns: #VALUE!) for the below Fortran code:

```
Function RANDGF()  bind(c)
use ISO_C_BINDING
implicit none
!GCC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: RANDGF
Double Precision  :: RANDGF
Double Precision  :: A

Call RANDOM_NUMBER(A)
RANDGF = 2.0
END
```

However, if I comment the `Call RANDOM_NUMBER(A)` line, the DLL returns the expected result.
The command that I use for the compilation is:

```
gfortran -shared -fpic -o randgf.dll randgf.f90
```

Here is my VBA Code in Excel:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function randgf Lib "randgf.dll" () As Double
Public Function gfort_res() As Double
   gfort_res = randgf()
End Function
```

What should I do in order to call functions like `RANDOM_NUMBER` in my code, if I want to use them in a DLL?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not return any result"? How is the function declared in Excel? Are you certain that you are building a 64-bit DLL and calling it from 64-bit Excel? I ask because 32-bit Excel wants the STDCALL calling convention, which will affect the stack. Please provide a [Minimum, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @SteveLionel: I edited my question and added the VBA code. I think now, all the required information for creating and testing this sample is provided. Also, it is now noted that by no result I meant, excel returns #VALUE! in the cell that the VBA function (`gfort_res()`) is called.
The whole story is about 64-Bit Version and I am sure about it (64-Bit gfortran compiler and Excel). It is also mentioned that when I comment the `RANDOM_NUMBER` function, the dll works.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main issues that leads to Excel to not execute the function:

---

One of them, is that Excel can't find the DLL file, and this is because,
even if the dll file is at the same folder of the excel worksheet, the Excel's
process current dir is not the same.

For this issue, there are two possible solutions:

*First*: At the function declaration, you can put the full path to the DLL file:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function randgf Lib "C:\myexcellib\randfunc\randgf.dll" () As Double
```

*Second*: Before calling the function, you can change the current dir to the dll folder:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function randgf Lib "randgf.dll" () As Double
Public Function gfort_res() As Double
   ChDrive "C"
   ChDir "\myexcellib\randfunc"
   gfort_res = randgf()
End Function
```

---

The second issue is that Excel can't find the function inside the DLL file.

And for this issue, there are two possible solutions, as well:

*First*: You can indicate the ordinal number of the funcition as an "alias" at the declare
clause (e.g. if the ordinal number is 1):

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function RANDFG Lib "randfg.dll" Alias "#1" () As Double
```

*Second*: If you are using fortran 2003 or later, you can indicate the binding **name** that will
be exported:

```
function RANDGF()  bind(c, name="RANDGF")
  use ISO_C_BINDING
  implicit none
  !GCC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: RANDGF
  Double Precision  :: RANDGF
  Double Precision  :: A

  call RANDOM_NUMBER(A)
end function RANDGF
```

---

**Important**: All of the VBA code should be inside a Module, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Dear @Gomiero: thank you for your feedback. I have put the DLL in the "windows\system32" folder, so that excel can find it and the VBA code is inside the module.
Once more, I want to point out that the DLL works fine, if I comment the `call RANDOM_NUMBER(A)` line. That means, Excel finds the DLL and it calls the Fortran function properly and returns the correct result (in this example the result is 2.0). 
The problem shows up, when I call `RANDOM_NUMBER` function in my Fortran code. Is there any DLL or any library, that is missing in my target computer.

Comment: @Moji I made a test here without change your code and I used the same compiler options.  For the tests, I used: msys2/mingw64 gfortran 10.3.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project) and Excel from Office 365 (en-US, latest version). Maybe, the issue is related to some environment setup?

Comment: @Moji I made the test again, the same way you told, and the issue is that Excel is unable to find the function in the DLL. Therefore, the solution should be change the bind at fortran code: `bind(c, name="RANDGF"` ; or put the ordinal number of the function at the VBA code: `Alias "#1"`.

Comment: I tested the code using`bind(c, name="RANDGF")`. In this case, in the VBA code the function name must be written in upper case, as it is specified in binding name, i.e. instead of "randgf" (the default format of export functions in gfortran is lowercase) it should be "RANDGF". But the problem with `RANDOM_NUMBER` is still existing. I am using exact the same compiler as you: msys2/mingw64 gfortran 10.3.0. The Excel on my computer is 32-Bit, therefore I test DLLs on other computer with Excel 365, 64-Bit, Version 16.0.14326.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason of this behaviour. Before running my DLL, I had to copy gfortran libraries to my target computer. I simply copied all the lib*.dll files form mingw64\bin directory to windows\system32 folder of my target computer and now the dll works fine and Excel returns the desired result.

Is there any way to automatically load required DLLs from mingw64\bin into my own DLL (randgf.dll) during compilation and linking at my source computer? I want to avoid copying all the lib*.dll files from mingw64\bin.

Comment: Asking new questions in an answer is unlikely to get you new answers. You'd be better off asking a new question.